# Simpler way to execute command from PowerShell prompt

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

The command below only works if I execute it from a Windows legacy **cmd.exe** prompt exactly like this:

```
powershell.exe -command "Write-Host -NoNewLine y ; sleep 2 ; Write-Host -NoNewLine y" | plink.exe ...
```

If I want to do the same thing from a PowerShell prompt, I have to do:

```PoSH
cmd /c powershell.exe -noprofile -command "Write-Host -NoNewLine y ; sleep 1 ; Write-Host -NoNewLine y" `| plink.exe ...
```

I'd like to know if there's a simpler & more streamlined way to do the same thing from a PowerShell prompt without breaking anything.

Comment: are you trying to echo 'y' character into the STDIN of plink.exe ??

Comment: Without testing (or maybe I don't understand your goal), I guess you abuse host output. For `stdin` you should use `System.Diagnostics.Process*`.

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm not asking "how" to do it. I need a "y" keypress twice with the correct respective timing and the `|` character to be treated the same way it does under cmd.exe.  I already posted the only two ways I could get the code working in the OP. successfully.  I was just looking for a shorter way to do it than the "working" command-linea I posted in the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Is your question "how do I pipe text to another program's standard input?" If that's your question, just quote the string and pipe to the program. Example:

```
PS C:\> "y" | plink ...
```

You would definitely *not* use `Write-Host` in PowerShell for this because output from `Write-Host` goes *only* to the host (screen) and cannot be redirected.

To pipe two `y` responses with a return in between, you would use this:

```
PS C:\> "y`ny" | plink ...
```

You say that `Write-Host` "works" in your scenario. This would mean the `y` keystroke actually isn't being passed (`Write-Host` does not produce redirectable output, as noted) and your command is only "working" completely by accident.

Comment: That's correct! Quoting as such defaults to `Write-Output` which keeps the text as an object.

Comment: I'm not asking "how" to do it.  The methods mentioned above will not work in my case; as, I need "y" keypress twice with the correct respective timing.  I already posted the only way I could get the code working in the OP. It doesn't affect the results either way if I use `Write-Output` or `Write-Host` for this case in my example.. as they both work.  Anyway, I was just looking for a shorter way to do it than the "working" command-line I posted in the OP.